# angular js accordian not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using angularJS with bootstrap, the accordian function is not working properly as the #forces me to a different page instead of actually making the accordian work. Is there anything i can do without downloading a whole bunch of stuff?

heres my code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./CSS/bootstrap.css">
<div class="accordion-group">
                            <div class="accordion-heading">
                                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#myaccordion" href="#first">
                                             Section One
                                </a>
                            </div>

                            <div id="first" class="accordion-body collapse in">
                                <div class="accordion-inner">
                                   Random words
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

    <script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script
     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular-route.js">          </script>

<script src="./JS/index.js"></script>
<script src="./JS/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you re-edit your post to list the libs you are using? accordion needs bootstrap.js file, did you include the file?

Comment: Yes i did, i included all the js files and html files for bootstrap. If i wasnt using angularjs it would work but because im using angularjs it doesnt

Comment: How do you use Angularjs?

Comment: this is just one snippet of my overall project, but when you load any type of angular js the accordion stops working

Answer (score 0):

Where is your jQuery lib?

This works fine [For test](http://jsfiddle.net/DR3c6/)

```
<div class="accordion-group">
<div class="accordion-heading">
  <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#myaccordion" href="#first">Section One</a>
</div>

<div id="first" class="accordion-body collapse in">
  <div class="accordion-inner">Random words</div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular-route.js">              </script>
```

Comment: reason its working here is because you dont have an angular js files. Just the html, which means the js wont do anything....

Comment: How about this one? http://jsfiddle.net/DR3c6/1/  Angularjs doesn't effect other JS functions if you use it in a right way.